# Object.keys on MouseEvent does not list all of its properties

Tags: javascript, loops, properties, mouseevent

The following code iterates through a click event, logging its properties. However, it seems that the event "hides" properties other than "isTrusted" resulting a `false` when calling `hasOwnProperty`

```
document.body.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    for(var i in e){
        console.log(e.hasOwnProperty(i),i);
    }
});
```

Log:

```
true "isTrusted"
false "screenX"
false "screenY"
false "clientX"...
```

Same thing is when you call `Object.keys(e)` the result is only the "isTrusted" property.

```
["isTrusted"]
```

Why is that? is there a way, other than for...in loop to list the event properties and values?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235864/object-keyskeyboardevent-only-get-one-istrusted-key-rather-than-all-keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object.keys(KeyboardEvent) only get one "isTrusted" key rather than all keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235864/object-keyskeyboardevent-only-get-one-istrusted-key-rather-than-all-keys)