# Object.keys(KeyboardEvent) only get one "isTrusted" key rather than all keys

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction(event)">

<script>
function myFunction(event)
{
  console.log(Object.keys(event))
  console.log(event)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I run above code in: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeydown
I expect get all KeyboardEvent object properties that documented in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

My goal is to [get the property of the difference between two objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930387/get-the-property-of-the-difference-between-two-objects-in-javascript) to compare two KeyboardEvent objects, but the linked solution does not work for the KeyboardEvent object, `Object.keys(KeyboardEvent)` only get one "isTrusted" key rather than all keys.

Comment: Not all properties are enumerable, and not all properties are on the object itself -- they can be inherited. See referenced Q&A that provides a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Object.keys only iterate over whose enumerable property is true  [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
function myFunction(event){

  console.log(Object.keys(event))
  console.log(event)
  
  for (const property in event) {
 
 if(typeof event[property] == "function"){ 
  console.log(`${property}: `+':its a  fuction');
  }else{
   console.log(`${property}: ${event[property]}`+':  its a property');
  }
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction(event)">

</body>
</html>
```